# ORA-01847 day of month must be between 1 and last day of month - but data is OK

Tags: sql, oracle, date

*Problem is solved - see end of this post.*

when i call to_date in select clause everything works fine - get a resultset of     12 records:

```
select value1,to_date(value1,'DD.MM.YYYY') 
  from variableindex 
  where 
    value1 is not null 
    and value1 <> '0' 
    and creation_time_ > to_timestamp('20140307','YYYYMMDD')
  order by 2
```

returns

```
'VALUE1'     'TO_DATE(VALUE1,'DD.MM.YYYY')'
'25.11.2013' 25.11.13
'12.03.2014' 12.03.14
'12.03.2014' 12.03.14
'12.03.2014' 12.03.14
'12.03.2014' 12.03.14
'12.03.2014' 12.03.14
'14.03.2014' 14.03.14
'14.03.2014' 14.03.14
'14.03.2014' 14.03.14
'14.03.2014' 14.03.14
'20.03.2014' 20.03.14
'20.03.2014' 20.03.14
```

Every datestring has been converted as expected.

If i add the following line to where clause

```
and to_date(value1,'DD.MM.YYYY') < to_date('20140301','YYYYMMDD')
```

i'll receive:

```
ORA-01847: Tag des Monats muss zwischen 1 und letztem Tag des Monats liegen
01847. 00000 -  "day of month must be between 1 and last day of month"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

No it really gets nasty... i changed my query to

```
where id_ in (...)
```

and used the same 12 recordsets ids as in original query. No Error...

Many thanks to @GordonLinoff - this is how i use the query now:

```
select value1,to_date(value1,'DD.MM.YYYY') from variableindex 
   where 
   (case when value1 <> '0'  then to_date(value1,'DD.MM.YYYY') end) >  to_timestamp('20131114','YYYYMMDD')
   and creation_time_ > to_timestamp('20140307','YYYYMMDD')
order by 2;
```

Comment: try select to_date('20140301','YYYYMMDD') from dual and check the output

Comment: i wonder why it should work in select clause but not in where clause

Comment: @Joggl . . . Is that really all the data in the table?

Comment: @GordonLinoff no but its all the content when using "and creation_time_ > to_timestamp('20140307','YYYYMMDD')"

Comment: This because filter `value1 <> '0'` for some reasons may be applied AFTER your conversion `to_date(value1,'DD.MM.YYYY')`.  Probably, this is an Oracle "feature", that looks like a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your query with the `where` clause:

```
select value1, to_date(value1,'DD.MM.YYYY') 
from variableindex 
where value1 is not null and
      value1 <> '0' and
      creation_time_ > to_timestamp('20140307', 'YYYYMMDD') and
      to_date(value1 'DD.MM.YYYY') < to_date('20140301', 'YYYYMMDD')
order by 2;
```

Oracle does not guarantee the order of processing of clauses in the `where`.  So, `value <> '0'` is not guaranteed to run before the last condition.  This happens to be a big problem on SQL Server.  One solution is to use a `case` statement:

```
select value1,to_date(value1, 'DD.MM.YYYY') 
from variableindex 
where value1 is not null and
      value1 <> '0' and
      creation_time_ > to_timestamp('20140307', 'YYYYMMDD') and
      (case when value <> '0' then to_date(value1, 'DD.MM.YYYY') end) <
          to_date('20140301', 'YYYYMMDD')
order by 2;
```

Rather ugly, but it just might solve your problem.

Comment: COMMON MAN - u did it!

Comment: +1 @Joggl Suspected this, but your comment to [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22426607/2899629) threw me off-guard.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `OracleParameter` in SQL with parameter name and value binding, check you set the `oracleCommand.BindByName = true` then it'll bind by name, and not by parameter adding order.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that we got the same ORA-01847 error when the user's web browser language encoding was changed from English to Portuguese.

The line of code that failed was:

```
IF TO_DATE(NEW_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') = TO_DATE(OLD_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') THEN
```

Which was fixed by rewriting it to:

```
IF TO_CHAR(NEW_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') = TO_CHAR(OLD_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') THEN
```

It appears Oracle detected the change of language and assumed the date value will be formatted for the Portuguese locale.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
CASE WHEN COLNAME='00.00.0000' THEN NULL
ELSE to_date(TRIM(COLNAME),'DD.MM.YYYY') END AS COLNAME

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trunc` instead of `to_date`:

```sql
select value1 from table
where trunc(value1) between '01-jan-2024' and '31-jan-2024'
```